# Is it possible to connect USB 3.1 Type C to ESP32?

Tags: usb-c, esp32

So, I once looked at the pinouts of USB 3.1 Type C:[image: USB C PINOUTS]

and I found out that there were RX and TX pins, but they had + and -. Is it possible to connect the serial pins to the ESP32,as there are two on my module and two on the USB type C:[image], how would I manage with a RX+/- and a TX+/-.  Are there any other pins that are supposed to be connected other than the serial pins, GND and VBUS to VIN?

Comment: Simply get a USB-C to micro USB adapter cable, or a USB-C to USB-A adapter and then a normal cable.  But it's not the ESP32 you are connecting but rather the CP210x on the module.

Comment: The TX & RX pins you're seeing are not serial pins. They're USB 3.x SuperSpeed pins.

Answer (score 4):

No, it isn't.

The TX and RX on the ESP32 are the serial transmit and receive pins for standard UART communications.

It is not in any way compatible with USB signaling.

At least you would need an USB serial port chip to have an USB UART which you can connect to UART RX and TX pins.

Answer (score 1):

As described by [Justme](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/527682/97482), the ESP32 itself does not support USB, but UART, which are completely different.

However, many **boards** with an ESP32 have a serial-to-USB converter, and that is connected to an USB port. Some boards have a type C connector, so you would connect directly to that (note that some boards have such a connector for power only, and do not have the serial-to-USB chip — check the specs of the board for details). Other will have a micro-B connector, in which case a simple adapter or cable converting from type C to micro B is enough.

Some boards do not have a serial-to-USB chip. There are then usually matching “programmer boards” which are just a serial-to-USB chip on a small PCB.

Note also that the ESP32-S2, which is a newer variant of the ESP32, does have a USB interface built into the chip. On the other hand, it lacks BLE.

If you are designing your own board with an ESP32 (not -S2) and want to include an USB port for programming / communication, you’ll have to pick a serial-to-USB chip. There are many on the market, though some have better driver support than other (on the computer you’ll connect the board to): some will just work out of the box, while others will require manual installation of drivers.

Comment: For the ESP32-S2 chips do you if it can be programmed by the built-in USB? Assuming I make a PCB with everything wired up properly can I just connect it to my computer and upload my code?